# Change My account link - WCFM (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress

Maybe someone knows how to Change "Account" button link here in Woocommerce. I want that it takes user to Pro dashboard ( WCFM ) not on my account ( standart Woocommerce my account ) . We can set it easily in settings- set my account pages as "Pro dashboard"but then it automatically changes adresses, and password recovery doesn't work, because its linking via standart My- account.

So i just need when i click on it, it goes to pro dashboard, and we are not seeing "my account"

Answer (score 0):

I'm only new to WP but I think if you go to the WP Dashboard > Woocommerce > Settings > Advanced > Page Setup you can change the My Account page

Hope this is helpful and not too late :)

Comment: specifically tell ur technologies

Comment: What do you mean?